# How can I post the results of a single Jenkins SonarQube scan to two different SonarQube servers?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have a Maven Java Jenkins job which has a Post Step which invokes the 'Execute SonarQube Scanner' with a scan task.

I have defined two SonarQube installations within the Jenkins configuration.

I can post to both servers by copying the 'Execute SonarQube Scanner' scan task and changing the SonarQube Installation.

This performs the scan twice.

Is there a method to perform the scan once and post the results to both SonarQube Installations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess no.

What you can do instead is, export and import entire project (after scan is complete) between SonarQubes (if feasible)

Refer it here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Project+Move

However, it is advisable to have a central SonarQube.

Comment: I am afraid this does not address the problem. I need a technique within the Jenkins server to post to two separate Sonar hosts.

Comment: Any specific reason to have 2 different Sonar hosts?

Comment: Yes. One is an Enterprise server the other is my local team's server.

Comment: Although below alternative might not be the desired solution, still have a try :

I will suggest to run the scan in developer's IDE (eg using SonarLint in eclipse). You can bind the project which is on your machine to that one of Enterprise Sonar. However, this scan will not be "centralized" within your team but every member from the team can scan their project locally with same configuration as that of Enterprise.